# This definition of a refinement of cone collections does not do a single thing it's supposed to

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, definition

I am currently working through a paper by Elsenhans and Stoll titled "Minimization of hypersurfaces", available on arxiv: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.04625.pdf

My questions deal with their definition of cone collections and refinements, which seem to be exclusive to this paper, section 5 (except for the definition of closed cones). I will recall the relevant definitions here to phrase my questions.

A **closed cone** is a closed subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is closed under multiplication by non-negative scalars, i.e. $x \in C, a \geq 0 \Rightarrow ax \in C$. Note that the intersection of two closed cones is again a closed cone.

A **cone collection** is a set $\mathcal{C}$ of closed cones in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that:

- The intersection of any two cones in $\mathcal{C}$ is in $\mathcal{C}$
- $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n \subset \bigcup \mathcal{C}$

Here  $\bigcup \mathcal{C}$ denotes the union of all cones in $\mathcal{C}$.

Let $w \in \mathbb{R^n}$. Then there exists a cone in $\mathcal{C}$, minimal with respect to inclusion, that contains $w$. Call it $\mathcal{C}(w)$. It is simply the intersection of all cones in $\mathcal{C}$ containing $w$.

If $\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{C'}$ are two cone collections, we call $\mathcal{C}$ a **refinement** of $\mathcal{C}'$ if every cone of $\mathcal{C}$ is contained in a cone of $\mathcal{C}'$.

Ok, first question. In the paper, in the proof of Lemma 5.7, the authors claim that if $\mathcal{C}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{C}'$ and $w \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$, then
\begin{equation}
\label{bla}
\mathcal{C}(w) \subset \mathcal{C}'(w).
\end{equation}

I believe that this is false: Not every cone of $\mathcal{C}'$ contains a cone of $\mathcal{C}$. Here's a simple counterexample:

Let $\mathcal{C}$ contain only the cone $C := \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n$, and let $\mathcal{C'}$ consist of the two cones $D_1 := \{(x,y) \vert y \geq -x\}$ as well as $D_2 := \{(x,y) \vert x \leq 2y \leq 4x\}$. Then $\mathcal{C}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{C}'$ since $C \subset D_1$. However, taking $w=0$, we have $\mathcal{C}(0) = C$ while $\mathcal{C}'(0) = D_2 \subsetneq C$. Therefore the statement should be false.

ES use this to make a statement about complete sets. A set $S \subset \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$ is **complete** for $\mathcal{C}$ if

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n \subset\bigcup_{s \in S} \left(s + \mathcal{C}(s)\right).
\end{equation}

ES then show that if $\mathcal{C}$ refines $\mathcal{C}'$ and $S$ is a complete set for $\mathcal{C}$, then $S$ is also complete for $\mathcal{C}'$. This is Lemma 5.7.

In our above example, this statement is also false. A complete set for $\mathcal{C}$ is $\{(0,0)\}$, but this is not complete for $\mathcal{C}'$.

The authors then go even further. They define cone collections via half-spaces: If $\mathcal{H}$ is a set of half-spaces, i.e. a set in $\mathcal{H}$ is defined by $\langle v, x \rangle \geq 0$ for some fixed vector $v$, and if the union of the half-spaces contains $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n$, then we can construct a cone collection $\mathcal{C}$ by taking all of the intersections of sets in $\mathcal{H}$. Then they claim that *if we add half-spaces to $\mathcal{H}$, then we refine the corresponding cone collection*.

This is important for the author's purposes, because they then proceed to add some half-spaces in a certain setting to create a refined cone collection, construct a complete set for this cone collection, then claim that it is also a complete set for the original cone collection.

Anyway, I claim that this is false as well. Take as $\mathcal{H}$ the set consisting only of the half-space given by $y \geq -x$ (this contains $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n$ so it's fine), then $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{H}$. Define $\mathcal{H}_0$ as consisting of the half-space in $\mathcal{H}$ together with the opposite half-space $y \leq -x$. The corresponding cone collection $\mathcal{C}_0$ then consists of three cones given by $y \geq -x$, $y \leq -x$ and $y = -x$, respectively. But now $\mathcal{C}_0$ cannot possibly be a refinement of $\mathcal{C}$ since the cone $y \leq -x$ is not contained in any cone of $\mathcal{C}$.

In the end, I believe that the author's original intentions still hold true. If $\mathcal{H}$ defines a cone collection $\mathcal{C}$, then
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{C}(w) = \bigcap_{h \in \mathcal{H}, w \in h} h.
\end{equation}

Thus if $\mathcal{H} \subset \mathcal{H_0}$ and $\mathcal{C}_0$ is the corresponding cone collection of $\mathcal{H_0}$, then

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{C}_0(w) = \bigcap_{h \in \mathcal{H}_0, w \in h} h \subseteq \bigcap_{h \in \mathcal{H}, w \in h} h = \mathcal{C}(w).
\end{equation}

So it should still work, but only if you completely forget about refinements. Since the logic seems to break down every step of the way, I thought that maybe the definition of refinements was flawed, but it is exactly the same definition that is given for refinements of open covers of a topological space in the case of Cech cohomology, for instance, and it seems pretty "natural".

So.... am I missing something here about refinements? Do these arguments really fall apart the way I described? Is the notion of a refinement of a cone collection flawed? Any thoughts on these notions are greatly appreciated, and if anything is unclear in my questions, then please let me know!